# Python: Dealing with a second operator in calculator

Tags: python, calculator

I am creating a calculator program and I am nearly complete. The last problem I am encountering is dealing with a second operator.

The program takes an expression with a maximum of two operators(ex.2/3*4). It splits it into 2,/,3,*,4 and the uses many varying functions to solve the expression. Now the specific part I am presenting below is the function that solves the first expression, (I have solved the rest of it already):

```
def firstOperationWithOneOperator(numEx1,numEx2,opEx1):

    if opEx1=="*":
        solution1=numEx1*numEx2
        print(solution1)
        return solution1
    elif opEx1=="/":
        solution1=numEx1/numEx2
        print(solution1)
        return solution1
    elif opEx1=="+":
        solution1=numEx1+numEx2
        print(solution1)
        return solution1
    elif opEx1=="-":
        solution1=numEx1-numEx2
        print(solution1)
        return solution1
```

So I now have a working function to solve something with one operator(ex.2/3) as you can see above. I needed some help finding out how to deal with a second operator while keeping the order of operations  in check. So how can I solve an expression such as 2+3*5? I will keep updating my OP with limitations as they are presented, if any. If anything is unclear please ask and I will edit the OP.

EDIT:

```
def fowoo(nums1,fowoo(nums2,nums3,ops2),ops1):
    print(fOWOO(nums1, fOWOO(nums2, nums3, ops2), ops1))
```

Comment: Don't think that you are close. You need to take operator priority into account in case you have 2 and more operators inside of your code. Try to look into reverse polish notation to solve this task(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)

Comment: what is a method to do it without implementing RPN?

Comment: Do you have to do all of this yourself (eg for assessment) or can you just use `eval()` and let python do the work for you?

Comment: @Tim: "_Enter your input:_ `subprocess.Popen(['rm', '-rf', '/'])`"

Comment: @Eric: Easier to validate input than to try and implement RPN or something similar.

Comment: @Tim No it isn't. RPN is nice because it's (fairly) easy to implement -- you push the characters onto a stack and then just pop them one at a time. Input validation for Python is basically impossible.

Comment: If this isn't an assignment, the [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module is probably the way to go.

Comment: @katrielalex: Input validation for a calculator is nice and simple. Just need to make sure every character is 0-9 or one of the allowed operators. Can do it with one loop. No validation would be required if he has made a GUI with buttons for input, depends where he is getting his input from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fOWOO = firstOperationWithOneOperator
```

You need to decide between:

```
fOWOO(num1, fOWOO(num2, num3, op2), op1)  # num1 `op1` (num2 `op2` num3)
```

and

```
fOWOO(fOWOO(num1, num2, op1), num3, op2)  # (num1 `op1` num2) `op2` num3
```

Based on the precedence of `op1` and `op2`

---

So:

- `2 / 3 + 4` -> `fOWOO(fOWOO(2, 3, '/'), 4, '+')`
- `2 + 3 / 4` -> `fOWOO(2, fOWOO(3, 4, '/'), '+')`

Comment: sorry I should mention I am new at programming. What exactly is going on between the two cases?Also I have never seen a function being assigned into a variable. Is that even common or allowed or are you trying to prove a point?

Comment: @user1716168: Which bit are you struggling with? Do you understand what the comments indicated?

Comment: yes, i can understand the documentation, so my question is... am I going to be implementing if-else statements to implement the two cases, how will I get my code to distinguish when to use those two?

Comment: The same way you evaluate operator precedence in your head

Comment: @Eric , can you send me a chat link, I feel like I almost have the hang of this but am still slightly confused...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19139/discussion-between-eric-and-user1716168)